# Change Galaxy S8 Navigation Bar Color Programmatically

Tags: java, android, xamarin, samsung-galaxy

Since galaxy s8 home/back/recent buttons are now soft keys, so i need to change the back color of the buttons within my application only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You problem is solved in Lollipop and above,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setNavigationBarColor(Color.YOUR_COLOR);
}
```

Comment: It's my pleasure to assist you...And never be worry  about down votes if you facing any problems.. 

Answer (score 3):

The question asked for programmatically which Dhruv Patel answered correctly

but for anyone else who stumbles upon this and is wondering how to do this in xml, open up styles.xml from /res/values-v21/styles.xml (if your minSdk is less than 21, otherwise just /res/values/styles.xml) and under your theme that you use in your  or  in AndroidManifest (I'm using 'AppTheme' across the entire ),

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    ...
    <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

insert the line under a theme in the styles.xml

```
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
```

and change the color to whatever you want so it looks like

styles.xml

```
    <resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Other items -->
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/hint_gray</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/RobotoButtonStyle</item>


        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
    </resources>
```

if your minSdk is less than 21 and you  don't have the styles-v21 setup you can just insert the line item in styles.xml and Android Studio's built-in tools will show the error and help create the directory